# D3.js Works on CodeCademy and not locally

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I created the following d3.js through http://www.codecademy.com/. The example works on codecademy but if I try to run it via my local server the .style("width", function(d) {return d;}); doesn't work. I.E. although the color of each div changes, the width does not.

Sampling the d3.selectAll("div") via Chrome command line reveals that the data stored within **data** is correct. I cannot see what I am doing wrong locally.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>d3 js beginning</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>one</div>
        <div>two</div>
        <div>three</div>
        <div>four</div>
        <div>six</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            d3.selectAll("div").style("background-color", "steelblue");

            d3.selectAll("div")
                    .data([55, 50, 65, 70, 22])
                    .text(function(d) {
                return d;
            });

            d3.selectAll("div")
                    .data([55, 50, 65, 70, 22])
                    .transition()
                    .duration(500)
                    .style("width", function(d) {
                return d;
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to add a unit to the width (i.e. "px") -- http://jsfiddle.net/zYcZG/

Comment: I had the same exact problem. For me this could be an accepted answer!